# Loading Javascript with sockjs-erlang

Tags: javascript, html, erlang, sockjs

I am using the sockjs-erlang for my website.
Everything is pretty smooth and clear but I have a problem with external javascript files.

I can load any css files or pictures from subfolders and it appears that I can also load the javascript too. but the javascript doesn't take effect.

So my html code look like this:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/citylist.css" />
    <script src="js/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.sockjs.org/sockjs-0.3.4.min.js"></script>
```

and the code in erlang sockjs looks like this:

```
handle(Req, State) ->

  Path = bitstring_to_list(element(1,cowboy_req:path(Req))),
  Path_Final = "./run" ++ Path ,

  {ok, Data} = file:read_file(Path_Final), 
  case lists:last(string:tokens(Path_Final, ".")) of
    "js" ->
       io:format("PATTHHHH JAVASCRIPT ~p ~n", [Path_Final]),
       {ok, Req1} = cowboy_req:reply(200, [{<<"Content-Type">>, "text/javascript"}],Data, Req);
    "css" ->
       io:format("PATTHHHH CSS ~p ~n", [Path_Final]),
       {ok, Req1} = cowboy_req:reply(200, [{<<"Content-Type">>, "text/css"}],Data, Req);
     _ ->
       io:format("PATTHHHH HTML ~p ~n", [Path_Final]),
       {ok, Req1} = cowboy_req:reply(200, [{<<"Content-Type">>, "text/html"}],Data, Req)
  end,
  {ok, Req1, State}.
```

So when I load the page on erlang side I manage to load the file snap.svg-min.js and the file exists and everything. but the load doesn't happen in the front end and I cant get the functionalities I want.

I have tried with other js files or loading the same in other ways and everything works but loading external in sockjs is the problem

What do you think I'm doing wrong?
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It looks like maybe you need to shove